# Incorrect data types when calling constructor

Tags: java

I am trying to create a small stock control program, where each StockItem has 5 instance variables, an itemID, an itemDesc, a price, a quantity, and a reOrderLevel. I have set my constructor in the StockItem file, and whilst trying to create a tester file to test all my methods i have come across a problem. When i try and use my constructor to create a new StockItem, i get the error:

required: String,String,Double,int,int
found: String,String,String,String,String

How can i fix this error? I'm not sure if it is an error in my constructor, or if the code in my tester file is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

here is my constructor code:

```
public class StockItem {

String itemID;
String itemDesc;
Double price;
int quantity;
int reOrderLevel;
//declaring my instance variables    

public StockItem (String itemID, String itemDesc, Double price, int quantity, int reOrderLevel) {       
    this.itemID = itemID;
    this.itemDesc = itemDesc;
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.reOrderLevel = reOrderLevel;
}
```

and here is my tester code so far, trying to create an item:

```
public class StockItemTester {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    StockItem item1 = new StockItem ("ABC", "iPhone 5", " 500", "3", "10");      
}    

}
```

Comment: do you know what a method/constructor _signature_ is?

Comment: The Error Message itself gives you a lot of information in this case.

Comment: On a side note, do you really want a `Double` object as opposed to the `double` primitive type?

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass the types according to the constructors signature:

```
StockItem item1 = new StockItem ("ABC", "iPhone 5",  500.0,  3,  10 );
                                 ^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^   ^^^ ^^^
                                String    String     Double  int int
                                itemId   itemDesc    price   qty reorderlevel
```

Answer (score 4):

You are passing in `String`s when your contructor requires distinct data-types like `int`s and `double`s.

You need to change your constructor so you pass in the correct data types:

```
new StockItem ("ABC", "iPhone 5", 500.0, 3, 10); // String, String, double, int, int
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this:

```
StockItem item1 = new StockItem ("ABC", "iPhone 5", 500, 3, 10);
```

Any value in quotes in a function call is treated as a string.

Answer (score 2):

The last two parameters have to be of type `int`, and the one before that a `double` as per the instance declarations in your class.

`StockItem item1 = new StockItem ("ABC", "iPhone 5", 500, 3, 10);`

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you are passing 5 strings to the method which wants 2 strings and 3 numbers.

Change your method call from:

```
StockItem item1 = new StockItem ("ABC", "iPhone 5", " 500", "3", "10");
```

to:

```
StockItem item1 = new StockItem ("ABC", "iPhone 5", 500, 3, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have quotes around the numerical parameters, i.e. 500, 3 and 10. The quotes mean that they are being regarded as `String` as opposed to a `double` and two `int`s.